# Combine two raster with PostGIS or gdal_calc

Tags: postgis, gdal-calc

I want to combine two rasters (GeoTIFF or PostGIS raster) so that the result is a table showing each combination of values and their count.

Example:

raster 1  raster 2

`1 2 3    40 40 10`

`2 3 3    10 20 20`

`2 3 1    10 10 20`

The resulting Table would look like this

`raster1|raster2| cnt`

`1|     40|   1`

`2|     40|   1`

`2|     10|   2`

`3|     10|   1`

`2|     10|   2`

`3|     10|   2`

`3|     20|   2`

`2|     10|   2`

Essentially this is what ESRI's `Spatial Analyst Tool` 'combine' does (really fast), by creating a raster and an associated value attribute table.

I was able to do this in PostGIS using the following code

```
with hw as (
SELECT val::integer as hw,geom as geom
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT dp.* FROM raster1 hw
         , LATERAL ST_PixelAsCentroids(hw.rast, 1) AS dp 
     ) foo1
)         
, beam as 
(

SELECT val::integer as beam, geom as geom
    FROM (SELECT dp.* FROM raster2 beam
         , LATERAL ST_PixelAsCentroids(beam.rast, 1) AS dp 
  ) foo2
)
, 
stats as
(

  select (split_part(combi,'_',1))::integer as hw
      ,(split_part(combi,'_',2))::integer as beam
      , n 
  from 
  (
    select  combi, count(*) as n from
    (  
        select  hw::TEXT || '_' || beam::TEXT as combi
         from hw, beam 
         where hw.geom=beam.geom 
    ) c
    group by combi
  ) g
)

select stats.esri_id, stats.hw, 100, 'Echaz', stats.n, 5
```

However, it works only for rasters which are not too large.
I have huge rasters 50000x50000)  , with those I run into memory problems quickly.

Comment: Did you try tiling your raster when loading it in PostGIS? The query becomes more complex but that should solve the memory problem.

Comment: The rasters were tiled for import (500x500).